# hashtag in apache .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

By using the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /api/web/index.html#$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

When user types the following URL at their browser.

```
http://localhost:8080/1/2
```

I'm expecting, Apache will perform internal redirection, and change the displayed URL at browser too (through R=301).

```
http://localhost:8080/api/web/index.html#1/2
```

Changing the displayed URL at browser is important. This is to ensure `index.html`'s JavaScript can parse the url correctly.

However, what I really get is

```
http://localhost:8082/api/web/index.html%231/2
```

I will get Apache error.

Apache false thought that, I wish to fetch a file named `2` located in directory `api/web/index.html%231/`

Is there anything I can solve this through modifying `.htaccess` only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `#` is getting encoded as `%23`. Try using the `NE` flag in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /api/web/index.html#$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```

the `NE` flag tells mod_rewrite not to encode the URI.