# URL rewrite in .htaccess Symfony

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I'm using Symfony. I have the following files.

- `/var/www/cheok/web/.htaccess`
- `/var/www/cheok/web/index.html`

My original `.htaccess` content is

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I wish, when user provide URL

```
http://myserver.com/123/456
```

the URL will be rewrite to

```
http://myserver.com/index.html#123/456
```

Hence, I modify the **original** `.htaccess` to the following

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /index.html#$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L,NE]

    ...
```

- `R=301` flag tells change the displayed URL at browser.
- `NE` flag tells mod_rewrite not to encode the URI.

However, it doesn't work as expected. URL rewrite doesn't work

http://myserver.com/123/456 - The server returned a "404 Not Found".
http://myserver.com/index.html#123/456 - (Works fine still)

Is there anything I can try out, to figure out why the URL rewrite doesn't work?

**Note, it once work without using Symfony.**

[hashtag in apache .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534318/hashtag-in-apache-htaccess)

Also, in my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, it looks like... I'm not sure whether it matters.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver.com
    #ServerAlias domain.com.localhost
    #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #ServerPath /api/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cheok/web
    <Directory /var/www/cheok/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It's called "Symfony", that's not so phony ..

Comment: Server can't get a hash parameter as browser not send it. Seems it's not a part of the HTTP standard.

Comment: Even I remove hash, it won't work still. It seems that `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /index.html#$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L,NE]` never get executed. But, I'm not sure how to verify it. and why that happen.

Comment: Try to escape the # symbol `\#` but I'm not sure that server put it to the `Location` header.

Comment: That's not the hash problem. As I tested to rewrite the URL to www.google.com, it won't work. It seems that the rule is not get executed, but I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're forwarding everything to `app.php` in Apache config you need to add this `301` rule there itself:

```
<Directory /var/www/cheok/web/>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.html#$1/$2 [R=301,L,NE]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But may I know, is modifying `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` for URL rewriting a good practice?

Comment: Since you already had a rewrite rule in server config that's the reason you needed this 301 rule there itself. Rewrite rules in server config is considered more efficient but changes in server config does require server bounce.